# Round up from .5 in a %

Tags: c#

Ceiling rounds up no matter if you get .1, .3, .5, .7. or whatever the value is for the decimal.

I need to know how to only round up if you have .5.  So for example [number].5 round up.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.Round()` uses banker's rounding by default, so it will round to the nearest even number when dealing with `[number].5`. In other words, `Math.Round(0.5)` is 0, while `Math.Round(1.5)` is 2. You can make it always round up by saying `Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Answer (score 11):

`Math.Round(0.5)` works as expected.

**EDIT**

`Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` rounds up if you're on 0.5

Comment: cool thanks, I thought it was that but wasn't quite sure.  I guess I could have tested? :P

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - less coffee, more MSDN

Comment: No, this is not the correct answer as 1.5 will round up to 2 whilst 2.5 will round down to 2, which is not what the OP wanted, i.e. it uses Banker's Rounding.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Yes, you could have. Use http://ideone.com/ or something if you're away from the IDE.

Comment: @Paul Ruane - I've added an example that answers the question.

Comment: @minitech: absolutely not. See the 'Remarks' section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx.

Comment: @minitech, I think you'll find it has been since David Kemp's last comment.

Comment: @Paul: Don't you just love Ajax sometimes :P

Comment: @David: I did 2 minutes ago. Don't you just love Ajax sometimes ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
Math.Round(number, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Details and comparison with the default can be seen on the [System.MidpointRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) page.